AWS-Parameters-and-Secrets-Lambda-Extension lambda layer intermittent timeout
When using the AWS provided lambda layer to cache secrets via the extension, I noticed the request to fetch the cached secret from localhost occasionally just hangs, hence the lambda intermittently  times out (99% success, 1% errors for me)
When using very standard code to fetch the secret (in nodeJs):
const getAWSCachedSecretsMgrSecret = async secretName => {
    try {
        const { AWS_SESSION_TOKEN } = process.env;
        const headers = { 'X-Aws-Parameters-Secrets-Token': AWS_SESSION_TOKEN };
        const SECRETS_EXTENSION_HTTP_PORT = 2773;

        const secretsExtensionEndpoint = `http://localhost:${SECRETS_EXTENSION_HTTP_PORT}/secretsmanager/get?secretId=${secretName}`;

        const response = await fetch(secretsExtensionEndpoint, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers
        });

        if (!response.ok) throw new Error(`Error in getAWSCachedSecretsMgrSecret! status: ${response?.status}. Text: ${JSON.stringify(response?.text())}`);

        const data = await response.json();
        const parsed = JSON.parse(data.SecretString);

        return parsed;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`error in getAWSCachedSecretsMgrSecret => ${error}`);
        throw error;
    }
};

module.exports = getAWSCachedSecretsMgrSecret;

I thought perhaps occasionally the extension was not ready yet (5 mins timeout) & lambda could not fetch it, so wrote in some retry logic:
const AbortController = require('abort-controller');
const retry = require('async-retry');

const getAWSCachedSecretsMgrSecret = async secretName => {
    try {
        const { AWS_SESSION_TOKEN } = process.env;
        const headers = { 'X-Aws-Parameters-Secrets-Token': AWS_SESSION_TOKEN };
        const SECRETS_EXTENSION_HTTP_PORT = 2773;

        console.log('AWS_SESSION_TOKEN => ', AWS_SESSION_TOKEN);

        const secretsExtensionEndpoint = `http://localhost:${SECRETS_EXTENSION_HTTP_PORT}/secretsmanager/get?secretId=${secretName}`;

        console.log('secretsExtensionEndpoint => ', secretsExtensionEndpoint);

        const data = await retry(
            async () => {
                const controller = new AbortController();
                const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
                    controller.abort();
                }, 3000); // Set per-request timeout to 3 seconds

                try {
                    const response = await fetch(secretsExtensionEndpoint, {
                        method: 'GET',
                        headers,
                        signal: controller.signal,
                    });

                    if (!response.ok) {
                        const errorText = await response.text();
                        const errorMsg = `Error in getAWSCachedSecretsMgrSecret! status: ${response.status}. Text: ${errorText}`;
                        console.error(errorMsg);
                        throw new Error(errorMsg);
                    }

                    return response.json();
                } finally {
                    clearTimeout(timeout);
                }
            },
            {
                retries: 3,
                minTimeout: 1000,
                maxTimeout: 3000,
                factor: 2,
                onRetry: (error, attempt) => {
                    console.log(`Attempt ${attempt} failed: ${error.message}. Retrying...`);
                },
            }
        );

        const parsed = JSON.parse(data.SecretString);

        return parsed;
    } catch (error) {
        const errorMessage = `Error in getAWSCachedSecretsMgrSecret => ${error}`;
        console.log(errorMessage);
        throw new Error(errorMessage);
    }
};

module.exports = getAWSCachedSecretsMgrSecret;

However it still occasionally fails 3 times then aborts.
Any solutions much appreciated! In the short term I may just fall back to the tried-and-tested fetch the secret myself and stash it in a variable outside the lambda handler for re-use over contexts.
